# MSSQL : SQLCMD not found

Tags: apt, software-installation, mssql

I am unable to install `mssql-tools`

```
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools
```

It gives the error:

```
E: unable to locate
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just to confirm, but you are trying to install `mssql` and not `mysql` right? Also, if it is `mssql`, are you trying to install a client or are you trying to install server tools?

Comment: @Owen `mssql-tools` is the tools that provide `sqlcmd`.  They're after the MSSQL tools.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure you set up the MSSQL repository for the `mssql-tools` and then install it.  **None** of the MSSQL stuff is available out of the box.

Caveats:

- 16.04 is the only available version of Ubuntu supported at the time of this post.
- Since this post, only LTSes are guaranteed to work, interim releases may work but LTSes are preferred environments.

([Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools#ubuntu))

> > NOTE FROM THOMAS WARD: These are from Microsoft, I don't necessarily endorse all their recommended procedures.
>
> #### Install tools on Ubuntu
>
> 1. Enter Superuser Mode
>
>    `sudo su`
> 2. Import the public repository GPG keys:
>
>    `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -`
> 3. Register the Microsoft Ubuntu repository:
>
>    `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list`
> 4. Exit superuser mode:
>
>    `exit`
> 5. Update the sources list and run the installation command:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get update
>    sudo apt-get install mssql-tools
>    ```